# Smart list to shuffle Christmas music (Kodi 15.x)

Tags: xbmc, kodi

This is my first year using Kodi.  I have a main library of general music.  The file structure for my music is always music > artist > album > songs.

I doubt it matters, but I'm using Kodi 15.x on Win10, Confluence skin.

I set up a generic smart playlist to read all music in my library and shuffle it (I have to say I can't believe how hard it is to tell Kodi just to shuffle a recursive directory full of music -- MediaMonkey, MusicBee et al do this drop dead simple -- point at a directory and say shuffle).

The problem is that I have a second directory full of Christmas season music.  Obviously I don't want that mixed into my general catalogue during playback and I don't want to spend a lot of time tagging stuff that can simply be segregated easily by directory.

The rub comes when I try to set up a second smart list to shuffle across my that Christmas directory.  Again, should be simple if I were using any other media player, but I can't seem to figure it out with Kodi.  It either starts mixing in non-Christmas music (which I don't want) or won't play anything at all.

Any chance of figuring this out before Christmas?  ;)

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you mention the first playlist, but here is a way without smart playlists:

Add the parent folder of your christmas folder to your files. Don't scan it to library.
Select the christmas folder, go to context menu (hit c if your using a keyboard) and choose queue media. Your songs will start playing, just go into the currently playing visualization and hit randomize at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll try that!

Comment: Okay, your idea is why I'm frustrated with Kodi.  As it was, I had the files set up as you suggested, but no "queue media" is available from the context folder.  The only way I can queue music in this context menu is if I go to a specific item and then only that single item is queued.  I cannot queue a folder.

Comment: sorry, "context folder" should have been written "context menu"

Comment: The important part is, that you point it to the parent folder to the Christmas folder. So that you can access the parent folder from your source list. Then hit the context menu on the Christmas folder. Worked for me when I tested it.

Comment: Oh, I get what you mean now... Thx